# Is it possible to create wix msi that will unpack an archive (zip)?

Tags: wix

I want that the msi will have inside it a dll and xpi file to use them as resources - and all in one file! without any cab files  (the msi installs a firefox and an internet explorer extensions).

Right now, the explorer extension project have a reference inside the wix project (to take the dll) and the firefox extension (xpi) is unpacked inside the project hierarchy to copy it to the installation folder when the msi is installed.

I'd prefer the project to have the packed extensions, and then copy/register/unpack them while installation.

Is it possible to have it all inside?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you aware of the `EmbedCab` attribute on the `Media` element?  This will embed the cab files within the MSI itself.

http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/media.html